# Could not link labels with centroids in Kmeans,Sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

How to know which label belongs to what centroids? The code below has produces the labels and centroids.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,0,0],
                 [0,0,6,7,8,9,10],
                 [11,12,13,14,15,0,0]])             
x,y = np.shape(data)
data_to_cluster = np.reshape(data, (x*y, 1))

km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=10, max_iter=5)
km.fit(data_to_cluster)

labels = km.labels_
centers = km.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: labels are just indices of centroids...

Comment: @yangjie then I wan to get the shape of original data (2d) using centroid values, but not using label values. Can you help me?

Comment: @yangjie Please feel free to asking me if you did not understand my question.

Comment: @yangjie I used `labels_2d = np.reshape(labels, (np.shape(data))`. How to do it using centroids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it is what you want: 
Get the center associated to the label of the points and then reshape it to the data shape.

```
output = centers[labels]
output = np.reshape(output, data.shape)
```